# High frequency of Bank Transfers without Card Reader

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, bank-account, money-transfer

I need to make a large number of bank transfers. At the moment I am doing each transfer manually through my online RBS account using a card reader. Due to this, each transfer is long and laborious.

Are there any ways of making bank transfers online, without using a card reader?

Comment: Are you willing to switch banks? Some use texts to approve, while others require a card reader to setup a new payee whilst allowing payments to an already approved payee with only a password

Comment: Yes, switching is fine. Ideally a list of banks and a "yes/no" card-reader requirement would be best

Comment: Lists are generally frowned upon - see [this official blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more on why

Comment: Do you have Barclays or HSBC ? Their initial setup is a pain, but after that they remember the payee and transfers are immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Various banks and building societies have different policies on how they approve transactions, and it should be possible to find one that fits your needs better. Often the first transaction to a new payee is treated more stringently than subsequent transactions. There's no reason you shouldn't ask how this works as part of deciding whether to move to a particular institution.

For example I bank with Lloyds, who currently authorise the first transaction with a new payee via text message, but after that will only require a password for further transactions with that payee.